# How in Cypher do I output a row number

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given a query like this

```
match (u:User)-[]->(p:Project) return 'x' as row_number, u, p
```

How do I output a resultset like this, with row_number being the row number?

```
╒════════════╤═════════════════╤══════════════════╕
│"row_number"│"u"              │"p"               │
╞════════════╪═════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│"x"         │{"name":"Martin"}│{"name":"Martin2"}│
├────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│"x"         │{"name":"Martin"}│{"name":"Martin1"}│
├────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│"x"         │{"name":"Bob"}   │{"name":"Bob2"}   │
├────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│"x"         │{"name":"Bob"}   │{"name":"Bob1"}   │
└────────────┴─────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with this:

```
match (u:User)-[]->(p:Project) 
with collect([u,p]) as col 
unwind range(0, size(col)-1) as un 
return un as row, col[un][0] as User, col[un][1] as Project
```

Which outputs:

```
╒═════╤═════════════════╤══════════════════╕
│"row"│"User"           │"Project"         │
╞═════╪═════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│0    │{"name":"Martin"}│{"name":"Martin2"}│
├─────┼─────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│1    │{"name":"Martin"}│{"name":"Martin1"}│
├─────┼─────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│2    │{"name":"Bob"}   │{"name":"Bob2"}   │
├─────┼─────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│3    │{"name":"Bob"}   │{"name":"Bob1"}   │
└─────┴─────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

Comment: I think yours is shorter => better. Well done ;)

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
MATCH (n)-[]->(m)
WITH COLLECT([n,m]) AS rows
WITH REDUCE(arr=[], i IN RANGE(0,SIZE(rows)-1) |
            arr
            +[[i]+rows[i]]
     ) AS rowsWithNumber
UNWIND rowsWithNumber As rowWithNumber
RETURN rowWithNumber[0] AS row_number,
       rowWithNumber[1] AS n,
       rowWithNumber[2] AS m
```